# Error when login using service principal in Powershell on Linux

Tags: powershell, azure, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed Powershell on Ubuntu 16.04 and trying to login using service principal.

Get Credential:-

```
$cred = Get-Credential -UserName $applicationId -Message "Enter Password"                       

PowerShell credential request
Enter Password
Password for user $applicationId: ********************************************
```

Login using service principal:-

```
Login-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $cred -TenantId $tenantId             Login-AzureRmAccount : AADSTS50001: The application named https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/ was not found in the tenant named $tenantId.  This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant.  You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.
Trace ID: 3e8b**c0-37b3-4835-9f4e-d59**100
Correlation ID: f79b**f4-8c0d-4d2b-8b80-b2d0**5784
Timestamp: 2018-01-11 12:32:37Z
At line:1 char:1
+ Login-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $cred -TenantId "0 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureRmAccount], AdalServiceException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.AddAzureRMAccountCommand
```

Kindly any one know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a known [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/4476). I test in my lab, I get the same error log with you.

```
PS /root> $PSVersionTable                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
PSVersion                      6.0.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
PSEdition                      Core                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
GitCommitId                    v6.0.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
OS                             Linux 4.13.0-1005-azure #7-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 8 21:37:36 UTC 2018                                                                                                                                                                             
Platform                       Unix                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

If possible, I suggest you could use Azure Cli 2.0 or login with Azure AD user.

Comment: Hi, do you use the latest Power Shell on linux? See this link https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/docs/installation/linux.md

Comment: I definitely need Powershell. I am using PowerShell v6.0.0 .

Comment: Unfortunately, the latest power shell has this issue. Could you use Azure AD user instead of Service principal?

Comment: I am trying to use Login-AzureRmAccount. I am getting error and asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219849/set-azurermdatafactoryv2-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet

Comment: I will check it.

Comment: Currently, Azure Data Factory Power Shell cmldet is not supported on linux. See this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azurermps-maclinux?view=azurermps-5.1.1#available-cmdlets

Comment: Power Shell on Linux is based on NetCore. It does not have full function of .Net Frame. So, many cmdlets are not supported.

Comment: I want do this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-powershell using Powershell. Is it possible to use Powershell on Azure portal itself

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163030/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-karan).