# 'Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-data-factory

I have installed Powershell 6.0.0 on Ubuntu 16.04. I am getting following error when trying to create Azure Data Factory using Powershell

```
Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2 : The term 'Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:16
+ $DataFactory = Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName $ResGrp.Re ...
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Then I tried to install the module and getting the following error

```
Install-Module AzureRM -AllowClobber  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          Untrusted repository                                                                                                                           You are installing the modules from an untrusted repository. If you trust this repository, change its InstallationPolicy value by running the  Set-PSRepository cmdlet. Are you sure you want to install the modules from 'PSGallery'?                                                        
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): Y
PackageManagement\Install-Package : The member 'TypesToProcess' in the module manifest is not valid: Cannot find path '/tmp/787167149/Azure.Storage/.\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Types.ps1xml' because it does not exist.. Verify that a valid value is specified for this field in the '/tmp/787167149/Azure.Storage/Azure.Storage.psd1' file.                                                                                 At /opt/microsoft/powershell/6.0.0/Modules/PowerShellGet/1.6.0/PSModule.psm1:2057 char:21                                                      + ...          $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters                                                                    +                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (/tmp/787167149/...re.Storage.psd1:String) [Install-Package], Exception                         + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_InvalidManifest,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestModuleManifestCommand,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, `Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2`  cmdlet is not supported on Linux. `AzureRM.NetCore` supports following services.

- Virtual Machine
- App Service (Websites)
- SQL Database
- Storage
- Network

More information please refer to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azurermps-maclinux?view=azurermps-5.1.1#available-cmdlets).

If possible, I suggest you could use Azure CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue in my machine by updating Az.DataFactory module.

- Install/update latest AzureRM.DataFactoryV2 module.
- Restart your powershell.
- try the above command.

it will work successfully.